# andorid room LiveDate return 0 normal query return objects

Tags: android, android-room

I have issue I have two query

```
@Query("SELECT * from parking")
fun getParkingList(): LiveData<List<Parking>>

@Query("SELECT * from parking")
fun getParkingList2(): List<Parking>
```

First query return 0 objects but second query return 4 objects , why it happend ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing because queries that return LiveData are asynchronous so it's 0 at that moment. If you are returning LiveData, then you should observe on it. For example something like this

```
parking.observe(this, new Observer<List<Parking>>() {
@Override
public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Parking> parking){

}
});
```